# Equivalent of Path.BitmapEffect in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

While I copied the XAML code from a WPF Pageto my SilverlightPage I found out that few of the prpoorties are not supported in Silverlight , mentioned bwlow:

```
<Path.BitmapEffect>
    <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="2"/>
</Path.BitmapEffect

ClipToBounds="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
```

Can any one please help with the Silverlight Equivalent proporties for the above mentioned WPF proporties.

Thanks,
Subhen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Path.Effect>
    <BlurEffect Radius="2"/>
</Path.Effect>
```

Clip to bounds isn't present in silverlight.

With SnapsToDevicePixels have a look at UseLayoutRounding instead.